# Why do non-ie browsers read IE conditionals with !important?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, cross-browser

When using an IE Conditionals (such as the code below) with !important, **regardless of the browser the background is defaulting to the background-color** with !important **even while inside an IE conditional**.

How could one rewrite this so that the browser accepts the background color in less than IE9 and the image (with height/width: 100%, no-repeat) in IE9 and other browsers?

Note: I plan to use this in a Wordpress site where the **theme is automatically setting the color or image** by default, so I have to use the !important to override the default theme styling.

```
body {
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
background-color:#c1beb2 !important;
background:#c1beb2 !important;
<![endif]-->
<!--[if gte IE 9]>
background-image: url("http://example.com/wp-content/example.png") !important;
background-position:left bottom;
background-size: 100% 100%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
<![endif]-->
<![if !IE]>
background-image: url("http://example.com/wp-content/example.png") !important;
background-position:left bottom;
background-size: 100% 100%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
<![endif]>
}
```

Comment: Could you sort out a jsfiddle so we can try it out?

Comment: That's... not how you use IE conditionals...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Conditional comments are meant to be used in HTML, not CSS.

That is, link to an IE specific style sheet like this in your HTML:

```
<!--[if lte IE 9]> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/ie.css" type="text/css" media="no title" charset="utf-8" />
<![endif]-->
```

That's the proper way to do it. If you don't want to create a whole other IE-specific stylesheet, you can rely on [CSS IE Hacks](http://www.webdevout.net/css-hacks#in_css).

Comment: Oh, let me try that and confirm it's working... 5 mins please.

Comment: Okay, I've added it right before the closing head tag:
`<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://example.com/ie.css" type="text/css" media="no title" charset="utf-8" />
<![endif]-->`
<![if !IE]>`
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://example.com/notie.css" type="text/css" media="no title" charset="utf-8" />
<![endif]>`
But it's not working still. What have I done wrong?

Comment: You want the IE-specific stylesheet to come **after** your main stylesheet, so it's specific CSS overrides your initial CSS. Remember, in CSS: the last style wins.

Comment: It is right before the closing head tag, and the rest are near the top, so that's fine. Any other ideas?

Comment: Well, you shouldn't need the notie.css file. You should just have your normal CSS file, with the background declared the way you want to appear in most browsers (using !important if need be). After your normal CSS file, have the conditional link to your IE-specific CSS, then redeclare the background that you want, probably using the !important declaration as well.

Answer (score 0):

ok wait a minute. As far as I know these(!) browser switches are not working in css. So you would need to make the switching part in html like this:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="IE9.css">
<![endif]-->
<!--[if gte IE 9]>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="IEgte9.css">
<![endif]-->
```

this however is kind of bad style. Normally you don't want to have browser individual styles. In rare cases you need too. Check the html5 boilerplate for some information about this.

Comment: I have a picky client who wants a background image to stretch 100% as a gradient. Have a better idea? It works great in ie9 (non compatibility mode) and chrome/firefox/safari... but not old browsers like ie8, etc.